# Reading gzipped package resources

Tags: python, gzip, python-importlib

I have created a Python library that you can install from PyPI. It opens a binary file (resource) from within a Python package:

```
with importlib.resources.open_binary(package_name, 'file.txt') as f:
    ...
```

Now I decided to compress `file.txt` to `file.txt.gz`. If it was outside a regular file I could
open it with `gzip`

```
with gzip.open('file.txt.gz', 'rb') as f:
```

or with `smart_open`:

```
with gzip.open('file.txt.gz', 'rb') as f:
```

But it lives inside of a library. How do I open `.gz` file in such a case?

Comment: use `__file__` to reconstruct path to `file.txt.gz` and mark your package as zip unsafe

Comment: @Marat Thanks. Can you elaborate on "mark your package as zip unsafe"? Why and how to do it?

Comment: https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#setting-the-zip-safe-flag

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with Python 3.9 and Pandas 1.5.1. My Pandas file is csv and has been gzipped.  The compression parameter to pandas lets it know what to do.

```
filename = 'file.csv.gz'
import gzip
with resources.open_binary("my.package.folder", filename) as fo:
    data_out = pd.read_csv(fo, compression="gzip")
```

In your case, with more general "txt.gz", why wouldn't we
look for similar approach.  I don't know what you think the exact correct answer would be, but consider:

```
import gzip
with resources.open_binary("my.package.folder", filename) as fo:
    with gzip.open(fo) as fo2:
        yy = fo2.read()
        zz = yy.decode("utf-8")
```

I'm almost sure that `zz` is exactly what you want.